# How to merge if/else statements in JS?

Tags: javascript, merge, if-statement

I'm wondering how to merge these JS if/else statements correctly?

```
if (window.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener('dosomething', foo, false); }
else { document.addEventListener('dosomething', foo, false); }

if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('dosomething', foo); }
else { document.attachEvent('dosomething', foo); }
```

EDIT I

The original code was:

```
if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('dosomething', foo); }
else if (window.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener('dosomething', foo, false); }
else { document.addEventListener('dosomething', foo, false); }
```

Now, I'd like to add

```
document.attachEvent('dosomething', foo);
```

here.

EDIT II

Turns out, "document.addEventListener" / "document.attachEvent" are redundant, so I'll leave it to

```
if (window.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener('dosomething', foo, false); } 
else if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('dosomething', foo); }
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What do you mean by "merge" ? Your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Please explain what outcome you are looking for. What is the net result you expect? ("Merge is ambiguous here.)

Comment: Hi! I'm new to this and would like to merge the two statements into one: if window.addEventListener do window.addEventListener else do document.addEventListener. if addEventListener not supported, try window.attachEvent else document.attachEvent... Hope that helps ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code looks OK except that it's better to check `window.addEventListener` first since that is the standard DOM Events interface. `attachEvent` should only be used as a fallback for IE versions before 9.

I don't know what you're doing with checking for the methods on both `window` and `document`. If the method exists on one it will by necessity exist on the other, so your extra option will never occur.

If there is neither `window.addEventListener` nor `window.attachEvent`, you are using an ancient browser or a limited (eg. mobile phone) browser. Neither of those will have the same method on `document`; if they support events at all you would only be able to bind using old-school `window.onsomething= function() {...};` style events.

Comment: @bobince, thanks for advising me! So, if I understand you right the "document.addEventListener" isn't needed at all?

Comment: I don't know, it would depend on what the `something` event is whether it should be bound on `window` or `document`. In a few cases there might be a reason to bind to both. But you can't tell what events will fire on an EventTarget just by sniffing for the method used to bind events, as that will always be present.

Comment: For the `load` event, `window` is the usual target. This should work everywhere. `document.body` also traditionally works everywhere for historical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Both conditions perform a different task, you should not join them. However, you may want to have a look at javascript **[ternary operator to lessen your code.](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/ternary.php)**

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to "merge" these if statements.  You are checking for two totally different things, even though they are related.  I strongly urge you not to.

Answer (score 0):

Leave them as they are.

If you really want to improve your code use a js library that can handle unified events for all browsers (i.e. jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_(.7c.7c)) to shorten it to this:

```
(window.addEventListener || document.addEventListener)('dosomething', foo, false);
(window.attachEvent || document.attachEvent)('dosomething', foo);
```

This works because the expression `expr1 || expr2` is evaluated as follows:

> Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, I suspect there's an inclination that 'these statements should not be merged!' and you offered an approach to do what shouldn't be done.

Comment: @babs: This is just a shortcut of your first two `if` statements. It doesn’t change the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't the advice to formulate if/else statements in JS like

```
if (foo) {
   bar();
} else {
   bla();
}
```

to avoid semicolon insertion issues?